# Force a browser to a specific resolution

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display a website on a 4k TV in a portrait view(2160x3840), which works fine for pictures with 1080x1920 resolution etc. My problem is that I need to display a webpage. I'm guessing the browser is 1024x768 or something, which makes the site stretched vertically on the TV. Can i force a browser into a certain resolution?

Comment: You could possibly do that (assuming you want to down-scale the resolution of the browser) but it's a bad solution to the problem. A much better idea would be to use media queries to make sure your layout works properly at any given resolution

Comment: "_browser is 1024x768 or something_" ... or anything, you can't predict the size of your users' screens.

Comment: I Think OP does not ask anything about HTML/CSS, but he has a Cloned Desktop to the TV, and because the TV and Monitor(most likely, Laptop) has different Resolutions, and Aspect-Ratio, he sees the Content stretched...

Comment: Everything else displayed is in 1080x1920, which makes it look like it's supposed to. This issue has been resolved already though. I found an add-on to the service I use that worked pretty much like photoshop. Everything is in order, but thank you all for taking your time to help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

> browser is 1024x768 or something

can be checked, what is the exact displayed size in pixels with dev tools on the device you are testing. The quickest way is to right-click space in the corner of the screen and inspect it. Usually, it goes to body element (if nothing is stretching above) and under computed you can see width and height. This should be same or nigh same all browsers.

Second, in most cases (unless you specifically agreed with the client) you are never sure on what kind of display your page will be looked, so DON'T focus solo on that screen size.

Third, yes you can force the browser to a certain resolution with calling:

```
function openWin() {
 myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
}

function resizeWin() {
   myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);                            
    myWindow.focus();                                     
}
```

Forth, it looks like a bad approach to the situation, considering the point two.